# What bias is responsible for people perceiving immediate and sudden value over long time value delivery as more?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, bias, time, validation

I have a scenario where people are receiving a massive value of not getting sick and dying in a relatively long period but not valuing it as much as short term solutions that make them feel better within shorter period with added risks.

*Percieved as more valueable*
[image]

*Percieved as less valueable*
[image]

To simplify magine getting 10 euros every day and 300 once a month. I have observed people perceive latter as more valuable and choosing that option.

Now I have to write a document providing scientific basic or at least some 3rd party source confirming said assumption. I think this is related to cognitive biases and delayed gratification perception but I don't actually know:

How to find scientific or credible sources supporting or exploring section of applied psychology related to subjective perception of value overtime and size of received value in instance?

On related note whats the maximum duration in which people atribute value to an action and where can I find proof for it?

**Edit:** Gaining money was a poor analogy. Its stopping damage/loss from ocuring.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_discounting

Comment: To directly answer the question it all sums up to how the money will be spent. Long term investions will favor a monthly income. Regular short term investions will favor an income of appropriate interval. Security is another issue. The probability of the magnitude and interval of theft, loss or destruction will require an income of appropriate interval.

Comment: @AzulShiva The of receiving value was inaccurate representation of situation:
Rather than receiving value will stop losing time and getting hurt. Its related to loss aversion.